# What is the language support across Windows 8 metro platforms?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, tablet

I am excited about the upcoming Microsoft Surface Tablet but I am confused by the differences between the tablet, phone and PC Windows 8/RT platforms.

I found the following API for developers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211369.aspx

But is is not clear to me if all of these Javascript/C#/C++ are supported on the phone, tablet and PC.

If I want to use the provided Microsoft API to write an application that is compatible with a Windows 8 Tablet, phone and desktop computer do I just have to use the API for a Metro style app? Or are there further restrictions on languages and API features depending on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Surface tablets are just really awesome Windows 8 PCs.  They won't require a specialized API set Though maybe there will be extra APIs available to get input from the fancy touch cover... I don't know they haven't said yet.  Likewise, they haven't given any useful details of how much Windows Phone 8 will have in common with Windows 8.  What we do know is that Windows Phone 7 is very much *not* compatible with Windows 8 - while many of the basics are the same between platforms, there are wide deviations in what APIs are available and how things work.

So on the desktop or Surface (which are the exact same platform), you can use Win8 APIs for Metro-style apps using JS, VB, C#, or C++.  On WP7, it's C# or VB only.  On WP8, it has been announced that we'll get the added option of C++ but not JS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there will be differences in the API based on the device. I don't think it makes sense to have all APIs on all devices - for example all the mouse related events on a phone.

I think they seem to be creating different API profiles with a common subset and very similar looking programming model on each device - so that porting code across should be very easy - especially if it is designed with portability in mind.

For example, on the C# side, the .NET Portable libraries help in creating assemblies which are binary compatible across different versions of Windows on devices.